Programmatically get playlist.m3u8 from web page running js player
I want to use an old TV set with an old RPi1 to display a news channel from a service I already have a valid subscription to.
The RPi should only display the stream using ffplay, for example. In fact, I wish I didn't have any mouse or keyboard connected to it.
On the News Channel page, which is accessed with proper authentication, I can use the Inspection Panel to obtain m3u8 for the live broadcast. It is the playlist.m3u8 selected in the screenshot.

However, the playlist URL changes every 24 hours or so.
Is there a way to write a program to get this URL without having to manually copy and paste every change that occurs?
I don't really understand how live streaming works.
I also know I'm not providing much information now nor what kind of information I should provide for help. So please be kind...
Important: There is no obscure intent here. I subscribe to the news channel provider and truly believe I'm not violating any law. Everything will be restricted to my home and for personal use.

How is the URL inserted on the page?  You'll need to figure out where it's coming from.  It might be on the page somewhere, in some JavaScript, perhaps from an API call, etc.   Once you figure that out, you can make a script to emulate that behavior to get the URL you need.  Alternatively, you can even automate a whole headless browser to get the URL and then play it with FFplay.  (Not sure if your Pi is fast enough, but you could even just automate setting the video element to fullscreen and using a real browser for playback.)

Also, have you considered that there might be a static URL for your steam out there already?  Many of the more major channels publish a variety of streams for different services.

@Brad I'll investigate that. Thank you.
